# ExtJS4: Grid with locked columns and summary

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have grid with locked columns. I want to see summary feature there.

grid config:

```
    ...
features: [Ext.create("Ext.grid.feature.Summary")],
...
var columns = [
            {
                header:"Somecolumn",
                width:425,
                locked:true,
...
```

I don't see summary here, but where I set column's locked property to false, summary appears. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a locked column to grid ext creates 2 different grid, 1 for locked columns and 1 for others.

When creating this grids it does not pass features to created grids.
For fix this problem you must override `Ext.grid.Lockable.injectLockable` method and copy features to created grids.

Here a fix for 4.0.7

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.Panel, {
    normalCfgCopy: ['invalidateScrollerOnRefresh', 'verticalScroller', 'verticalScrollDock', 'verticalScrollerType', 'scroll', 'features'],
    lockedCfgCopy: ['invalidateScrollerOnRefresh', 'features']
});
```